# Detecting memory corruption

Tags: c, memory-corruption

When I was working on big project I just realized it crashes after few hours of run. I tried debug it with valgrind and gdb but they didn't show me anything wrong. I tried change code to debug things easier but when I add printf or some function call corruption place changes so I can never find exactly how corruption happens. Corruption place also changes with different compiler and different compile parameter(like -g -Og -O1 -O2 -O3).

I'm not sure about terms but I know two type of corruption detecting; compile time and runtime.

And two type of corruption; stack corruption and heap corruption.

I made few programs to try detect memory corruption It would be good if someone can explain things I failed or misunderstood. Note magic define is specific to platform/compiler

stack example 1: print is 7. no warning with gcc. clang gives warning with `-Wall` from `-Warray-bounds`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
  int a[1];
  int x;
}atype;

int main(){
  atype var;
  var.x = 5;
  var.a[1] = 7;
  printf("%d\n", var.x);
  return 0;
}
```

stack example 2: print is 7. no warning with gcc. clang gives warning with `-Wall` from `-Warray-bounds`

```
#define magic 40

#include <stdio.h>

void func(){
  char stack[1];
  stack[magic] = 7;
}

int main(){
  char x;
  x = 5;
  func();
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

stack example 3: print is 7. gcc and clang doesn't give warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *a, int start, int end){
  for(; start < end; start++){
    a[start] = 7;
  }
}

int main(){
  char a[1];
  char x;
  x = 5;
  func(a, -1, 0); /* let's say we give wrong start end */
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

stack example 4 extension: print is 7. gcc and clang doesn't give warning.

```
#define magic 23

#include <stdio.h>

char func(int size){
  char a[size];
  char x;
  x = 5;
  a[size + magic] = 7;
  return x;
}

int main(){
  printf("%d\n", func(16));
  return 0;
}
```

stack example 5 gcc only: print is 7. gcc doesn't give warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int size){
  struct{
    int a[size];
    int x;
  }s;
  s.x = 5;
  s.a[size] = 7;
  return s.x;
}

int main(){
  printf("%d\n", func(2));
  return 0;
}
```

stack example 6 alloca: print is 7. gcc and clang doesn't give warning.

```
#define magic 7

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char func(int size){
  char *a = alloca(size);
  char x;
  x = 5;
  a[size + magic] = 7;
  return x;
}

int main(){
  printf("%d\n", func(16));
  return 0;
}
```

heap example: print is 7. gcc and clang doesn't give warning. valgrind doesn't give anything.

```
#define magic 23

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
  int x;
  int a[magic];
  int y;
}atype;

int main(){
  atype *mx = malloc(24);
  atype *my = malloc(24);
  my->x = 5;
  mx->y = 7;
  printf("%d\n", my->x);
  return 0;
}
```

Stack example 1 2 gives warning from clang so we can realize it easily. stack example 4 5 6 are not very standard.

Most things bothers me are stack example 3 and heap example because I use that ways in my code very much. How we can detect them?

Comment: Since you're using clang already, have you tried building with the address sanitizer?

Comment: When all you have is a pointer, the compiler really *can't* warn about going out of bounds. And even if the compiler can help with *some* cases, it's your responsibility as a programmer to make sure your program doesn't have undefined behavior,

Comment: @Useless It looks useful thing but in heap example it doesn't say anything too

Comment: If the compiler can't detect problems, then it has to be detected at runtime. With testing (automatic and manual) and sanitizers or memory debuggers (or both).